# If $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n>0$, then there exists circle $C$ of radius $R$ such that $\int_{C} \frac{P^{\prime}(z)}{P(z)} dz=2n\pi i $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n>0.$ Could anyone advise me on how to show there exists $R>0$ such that if $C$ is the circle $|z|=R$ anticlockwise oriented, then $\begin{align}\int_{C} \dfrac{P^{\prime}(z)}{P(z)} dz=2n\pi i\end{align} \  ?$

My attempt: By Argument principle, $\begin{align}\int_{C} \dfrac{P^{\prime}(z)}{P(z)} dz \end{align} \leq 2n\pi i.$ Since $P$ has at most countable number of zeroes, there exists a circle of radius $R$, sufficiently large, so it encloses all the zeros of $P \ ?$

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: polynomials are entire functions. So that means, that while a polynomial of degree n
 will have exactly n roots(counting multiplicity), it will also have zero poles inside a closed 
  a circle of radius R, sufficiently large, so it encloses all the zeros of P. 
Therefore according to the argument principle [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle] we get what you want. I think your thought was right.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG we may assume $P$ is monic. Let $P(z)=(z-a_1)\cdots(z-a_n)$ then $\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}=\frac{1}{z-a_1}+\cdots\frac{1}{z-a_n}.$($\frac{f'}{f}$this is sometimes called logarithmic derivative of $f.$) Then choose a circle big enough that contains all $a_k$. So $\int_C \frac{1}{z-a_k}=2\pi i$ for $k=1\cdots n.$ Thus $\int_C \frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}dz=2n\pi i$